# Trying to set onClick() on other buttons

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, android-asynctask

I'm new in android development. First I saved data in database with a button using AsyncTask. And now I'm trying to call intents on other buttons in same activity but nothing happens when i click on second button. Can anyone help me plz.. Here I'm posting some code too.

MainActivity.java

```
     //initialize all view objects
    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 AddBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    spn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    NextBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

SQLcon = new SQLController(this);
    // opening database
    SQLcon.open();

    loadtospinner();
}

    public void onClick(View v){

        if(v.getId() == R.id.btn_add){
          new MyAsync().execute();

            }
        else {
            Intent  in=new Intent(Intent, Second.class);
        startActivity(in);

        }



    }

    public void loadtospinner() {

        Cursor c = SQLcon.readData();
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {

            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME));
            al.add(name);
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> aa1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, R.id.textView1,
                al);

        spn.setAdapter(aa1);

        // closing database
        SQLcon.close();

    }




    private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
            PD = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            PD.setTitle("Please Wait..");
            PD.setMessage("Loading...");
            PD.setCancelable(false);
            PD.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String name = et.getText().toString();
            // opening database
            SQLcon.open();
            // insert data into table
            SQLcon.insertData(name);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            loadtospinner();
            PD.dismiss();
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: please post your stacktrace!

Comment: Actually, there is no error. Another button works as a dummy button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `implements OnClickListener` in your activity

than `setOnClickListener` to the `button`  like

```
 AddBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
_AddBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    NextBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
_NextBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Now in `onClick`

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_add:
        //all your operetion here for this button 

              new MyAsync().execute();
    break;

    case R.id.button1:
        //write what u want to do with " NextBtn " button  click 
          Intent  in=new Intent(this, Second.class);
        startActivity(in);

        break;
}


    }
```

Comment: thanks. It works finally. I'm new developer. Can you plz tell me how I can open selected text from first screen to next screen's edittext?

Comment: Pass the text value as string from first activity and get the same text in other activity and set in edit text .

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(SendingActivity.this,RecievingActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("keyName", value);  // values and retrieve them in the other Activity using keyName
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1):

change below thing

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

after that in on create

```
secondButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rightButton);
        secondButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

override below method

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) { // Parameter v stands for the view that was clicked.  

        // getId() returns this view's identifier.
        if(v.getId() == R.id.leftButton){
            // setText() sets the string value of the TextView
            changingTextView.setText("You clicked First");
        }else if(v.getId() == R.id.rightButton){
            changingTextView.setText("You clicked Second");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm calling asyncTask on first button. Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Intent instead of activity, pass the activity by Change this

```
Intent  in=new Intent(Intent, Second.class);
        startActivity(in);
```

and try

```
Intent  in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);
            startActivity(in);
```

Hope this work

Comment: No, I don't debug beacuse I don't know how to debug.

Comment: hmm, then you write a log and watch your log-cat, is your button click is working or not